# Replace a child node of BST with a grandchild in Rust

Tags: rust, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement removing of a node. When the node does not have children, I simply modify the parent's left or right. When the node has either left or right subtree, how could I remove the node and preserve its subtree?

Here is TreeNode implementation:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
  pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}

impl TreeNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    TreeNode {
      val,
      left: None,
      right: None
    }
  }
}
```

The implementation is given and cannot be changed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
let right_node = node.as_mut().unwrap().borrow_mut().right.take().unwrap(); // It may be the left child.
node.replace(right_node);
```